# How to auto connect PPPoE on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint

So, I have Linux Mint 19.3 with PPPoE connection through Network Manager and after i restart my pc this connection is lost, so I have to re-enter my user and password every time I turn on my pc.How to auto connect? I don't want to use `sudo pppoeconf` because it's the same thing.

"Automatically connect to this network when it is available" is checked, also what value do I have to set on "connection priority for auto-activation? That one is always set to "0".

Comment: In the PPPoE setup area, is there an auto-reconnect setting?  There is such a setting in a router that supports PPPoE

Comment: There isn't an auto-reconnect setting,also my connection is not through a router.

Comment: I figured that would be the case. It might be better for you to get a compliant router that supports PPPoE to make the connection and supports auto-reconnect

Comment: I have a router but i don't wanna use it.These are the options that i have in settings:https://imgur.com/a/jIYem5m

Comment: There is no reconnect possibility so you are (I think) out of luck. There was a VPN reconnect setting  so the OS writers probably did not think equally about PPPoE

Comment: Ok,maybe in the future i will install ubuntu,because it's auto-reconnecting.

Comment: I am looking at my Ubuntu machine (18.04) and it appears to offer automatic connection so it may work for you

Comment: Yes,i will try Ubuntu in the future.